# "Undefined property: Interceptor::$invoiceService" while overriding controller in magento2

Tags: magento2

I am trying to override "Adminhtml\Order\Invoice\Save" controller, So I made changes in di.xml as below  -

```
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Invoice\Save" type="Customcode\Productserialno\Controller\Sales\Adminhtml\Order\Invoice\Save" />
```

And create as save.php controller at location  - 
**Customcode\Productserialno\Controller\Sales\Adminhtml\Order\Invoice\Save.php**

and overide its execute function like below  -

```
namespace Customcode\Productserialno\Controller\Sales\Adminhtml\Order\Invoice;

    class Save extends \Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Invoice\Save
    {

        public function execute()
        {
           /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
            ====
            ....................
            ........................
            default code............
            ......................

            try {
                $invoiceData = $this->getRequest()->getParam('invoice', []);
                $invoiceItems = isset($invoiceData['items']) ? $invoiceData['items'] : [];

                /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order */
                $order = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);
                if (!$order->getId()) {
                    throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__('The order no longer exists.'));
                }

                if (!$order->canInvoice()) {
                    throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                        __('The order does not allow an invoice to be created.')
                    );
                }
                //====on below line its giving error========     
                $invoice = $this->invoiceService->prepareInvoice($order, $invoiceItems);

                if (!$invoice) {
                    throw new LocalizedException(__('We can\'t save the invoice right now.'));
                }

                if (!$invoice->getTotalQty()) {
                    throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                        __('You can\'t create an invoice without products.')
                    );
                }
                $this->registry->register('current_invoice', $invoice);
                if (!empty($data['capture_case'])) {
                    $invoice->setRequestedCaptureCase($data['capture_case']);
                }

                if (!empty($data['comment_text'])) {
                    $invoice->addComment(
                        $data['comment_text'],
                        isset($data['comment_customer_notify']),
                        isset($data['is_visible_on_front'])
                    );

                    $invoice->setCustomerNote($data['comment_text']);
                    $invoice->setCustomerNoteNotify(isset($data['comment_customer_notify']));
                }

                $invoice->register();

                $invoice->getOrder()->setCustomerNoteNotify(!empty($data['send_email']));
                $invoice->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);

                $transactionSave = $this->_objectManager->create(
                    'Magento\Framework\DB\Transaction'
                )->addObject(
                    $invoice
                )->addObject(
                    $invoice->getOrder()
                );
                $shipment = false;
                if (!empty($data['do_shipment']) || (int)$invoice->getOrder()->getForcedShipmentWithInvoice()) {
                    $shipment = $this->_prepareShipment($invoice);
                    if ($shipment) {
                        $transactionSave->addObject($shipment);
                    }
                }
                $transactionSave->save();
                //=================
                //===My custom code========
                //=================
                //....................
                ........................
                default code............
                ......................

                return $resultRedirect->setPath('sales/order/view', ['order_id' => $orderId]);
            } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                echo "<pre>"; 
                print_r($e->getMessage()); die;
                $this->messageManager->addError(__('We can\'t save the invoice right now.'));
                $this->_objectManager->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->critical($e);
            }
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('sales/*/new', ['order_id' => $orderId]);
        }
    }
```

On this line its giving me error -

```
$invoice = $this->invoiceService->prepareInvoice($order, $invoiceItems);
```

**Error - :** Notice: Undefined property: Customcode\Productserialno\Controller\Sales\Adminhtml\Order\Invoice\Save\Interceptor::$invoiceService in /var/www/html/git_projects/testbeat/app/code/Customcode/Productserialno/Controller/Sales/Adminhtml/Order/Invoice/Save.php on line 51

Please let me know what I am doing wrong .

Thanks

Comment: remvoe var folder and check

Comment: Hi Rakesh, I removed all directories of var, pub/static then again run upgrade, content deploy n flush cache but still giving same issue....

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The scope of this variable is **private**. Hence you can't use this in your overriding (inherited) class. please inject `Magento\Sales\Model\Service\InvoiceService` class for this variable in your constructor as it is injected into the main class.

Don't forget to run upgrade and di:compile commands after DI.

**Edit:** try this in your class

```
<?php

namespace Customcode\Productserialno\Controller\Sales\Adminhtml\Order\Invoice;


use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\InvoiceSender;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\ShipmentSender;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ShipmentFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Service\InvoiceService;

class Save extends \Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Invoice\Save
{
    /**
     * @var InvoiceService
     */
    private $invoiceService;

    public function __construct
    (
        Action\Context $context,
        Registry $registry,
        InvoiceSender $invoiceSender,
        ShipmentSender $shipmentSender,
        ShipmentFactory $shipmentFactory,
        InvoiceService $invoiceService
    )
    {
        $this->invoiceService = $invoiceService;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $invoiceSender, $shipmentSender, $shipmentFactory, $invoiceService);
    }

    /**
     * Save invoice
     * We can save only new invoice. Existing invoices are not editable
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     *
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        ..........................
        .......All code with customization------
    }
}
```

=================My Code is this ===================

```
namespace Customcode\Productserialno\Controller\Sales\Adminhtml\Order\Invoice;

class Save extends \Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Invoice\Save
{
    /**
     * @var InvoiceService
     */
    private $invoiceService;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action $context,
        Registry $registry,
        InvoiceSender $invoiceSender,
        ShipmentSender $shipmentSender,
        ShipmentFactory $shipmentFactory,
        InvoiceService $invoiceService
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $invoiceSender, $shipmentSender, $shipmentFactory, $invoiceService);
    }

  public function execute() { 
..........................
.......All code with customization------
}

}
```

Plz check because my code still giving same error. 
**Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Customcode\Productserialno\Controller\Sales\Adminhtml\Order\Invoice\Save::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Backend\App\Action,**

Plz let me know what I m doing wrong.

Comment: I tried like this inside class  -  

`private $invoiceService;

    public function __construct(
        Magento\Sales\Model\Service\InvoiceService $invoiceService
    ) {
        $this->invoiceService = $invoiceService;
    }` 
but its giving 500 error ....

Comment: did you run upgrade and compile commands afterwards??

Comment: yes I have run Upgrade command but not compile because i m already in developer mode, >>>> now defined it as  -
`public function __construct(
  \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Service\InvoiceService $invoiceService,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->invoiceService = $invoiceService;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }`

Now its giving -   Argument 2 passed to Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Invoice\Save::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\Registry, error...

Comment: ->  can you plz add respective live of code via  update your answer.

Comment: @Atul I have made an edit. please give it a shot.

Comment: I have added mine code in your answer, plz check. Because it still giving error.

Comment: @Atul PLease have a look at my edited answer and try that.